# Проблема с методом таймер

Tags: java, javafx, методы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Секунды не уменьшаются, программа сразу же после нажатия кнопки выдает те цифры"1:03", и дальше ничего. Пробовал break убрать, выдает "0:0".

```
public void TIMER_funk(int  sec) {
          timer_sec.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() { 
               int seconds = sec;
             while (--seconds > 0) {

  MINUTES.setText(String.valueOf(seconds / 60));
  SECONDS.setText(String.valueOf(seconds % 60));
  break;
             }  

           if(seconds % 60==1||seconds % 60==2||seconds % 60==3||seconds % 60==0){
           SECONDS.setTextFill(Color.RED);}else{SECONDS.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);}
           if(seconds % 60==1||seconds % 60==2||seconds % 60==3||seconds % 60==4||seconds % 60==5||seconds % 60==6||
                   seconds % 60==7||seconds % 60==8||seconds % 60==9){
               SECONDS.setText("0"+String.valueOf(seconds % 60)); 
           }  }
});  }   }, 1000, 1000);   

    }
```

ОШИБКА!!! ВЫДАЕТ ОШИБКУ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то вроде:

```
public void TIMER_funk(int  sec) {
  seconds_left = sec;
  timer_sec.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() { 
          if (seconds_left> 0) {
            seconds_left--;
            int minutes = seconds_left / 60;
            int seconds = seconds_left % 60;

            SECONDS.setTextFill(seconds < 4 ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
            MINUTES.setText((minutes < 10?"0":"") + minutes);
            SECONDS.setText((seconds < 10?"0":"") + seconds);
           }  
       }  
     });
    }   
  }, 1000, 1000);   
}
```

Думаю, стоит также предусмотреть событие остановки таймера по достижении нуля.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но ошибку выдает.

Comment: Ну скопируйте аргумент в поле класса. Или вообще перенесите

Comment: Спасибо вам, вы меня спасли.

Comment: @Kolia, главное, чтобы это не было тестовым заданием при приёме на работу ;)

Comment: )) спасибо учитель, вы мудрец 21 века, столько ответов дали людям.